# How to load my own map in indoor map app?

Tags: here-api

I tried to run the indoor_map_app example in navigate\flutter but it shows a blank map, How can I load my own map to the example or get the venue id to search for it and load my own indoor map in the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the HERE team already create the indoor map for you? Then you should have received a map ID (venue ID) which you can also enter inside the example application.

But just for your information, I think it's hard to find that info on the HERE website: You are just able to use indoor maps if you have a contract with HERE. Then you can provide them floor plans of your building and they will create an indoor map for you.

Comment: Correct. More info can be found in the documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.11.3.0/dev_guide/topics/venues.html